# Emitting a poll/select event from a timer handler through a wait queue

Tags: linux, select, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module

I'm writing a Linux character driver for a custom lab hardware attached to a development board with a slow ARM SoC and got stuck trying to implement a suitable notification system from kernel space to user space.

Basically, I read data from the HW periodically (every 10 ms), process this data through some filters running in kernel space (this part is ok), and notify the user space when some conditions are met. My approach is make the user space daemon wait a notification from the driver  with a `poll()` system call (natural, as I'm also monitoring a network socket there).

- on driver initialization, I create the timer (with `setup_timer`) that will call the function responsible for reading the hardware, set the GPIOs used for that, and create a wait queue (with `init_waitqueue_head`) to signal the `.poll` handler in `struct file_operations` from the timer handler. This part seems ok.
- There is a `.unlocked_ioctl` handler to set and get the conditions, but this part is working.
- my `.read` method from `struct file_operations` just puts a single byte with the status to user space; It never blocks as there is always a valid one (including the 'W' for "waiting more data from the sensors").
- Once the device is open, I enable the timer. Its handler function is called after 10 ms, reads data from the HW, runs through the filter, and sets the timer to run again (with `mod_timer`); If the filtered data match my conditions, it changes the status, sets a flag `poll_evt_waiting` to 1 and calls `wake_up_interruptible` on the queue shared with the `.poll`method from `struct file_operations`. This method is just:

  ```
  static unsigned int firflt_file_poll(struct file *filp, poll_table *wait)
  {
      unsigned int mask = 0;
      poll_wait(filp, &firflt_queue, wait);
      if (poll_evt_waiting != 0) {
          mask = POLLIN | POLLRDNORM;
          poll_evt_waiting = 0;
      }
      return mask;
  }
  ```

Problem is: the `poll()` in my user space daemon never receives a notification from the driver! Is there any obvious error in my approach? Specially regarding the wait queue? I never implemented the "other side" of a poll() before, and got all information regarding this from "Linux Device Drivers", 2005 ed.

If a read the devices file descriptor continuosly, I can see the status changes from user space, but this puts my daemon in a busy loop, which is too much for the slow CPU. I really need to keep it waiting in the poll until there is something new.

Also, the only operations I do with the wait queue is initializing it with `init_waitqueue_head`, waking it up with `poll_evt_waiting` when status changes, and passing it to `poll_wait` in my `.poll` handler. Is this approach sound?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call `wake_up_interruptible()` on the polled queue just force the `.poll` method to *be called again*. User space process receive notification **only when** `.poll` method *returns mask* which have polled bits set.

Check that your `.poll` method actually returns non-zero mask.

Comment: Interestingly, it worked after I changed the way I was setting flag `poll_evt_waiting`. There should be some unexpected concurrence somewhere.